# How can i add a block below the content of a node?

Tags: blocks

I created many blocks and used them in my nodes regarding to contet types.

But i need another thing.
I created new block.
In the "/admin/structure/block" page i dragged this block to "Content" region.
The block appeared in content region. But it appeared above the node body.

In content part of "/admin/structure/block" there is 2 blocks:
"Main page content" and "My own block".
My own block is below the other block. But still it appears above the content body.
Should i pay attention any other thing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to drag the block around in the `admin/structure/block` page. For instance drag it above the content block, and then back down to below. Then be sure and click 'Save.' :-)

Comment: There are times when both the drag thing and the setting the row weights won't work. What could be other alternatives

Answer (score 5):

In the Block UI at admin/structure/block toggle "Show Row Heights"

[image]

Set the weights manually to ensure they are correct.

[image]

Comment: Probably a better solution than mine.

Comment: Whatever works. :)